# Best strategy for using child classes with bindings and in general

Tags: c#, wpf

I believe this is a software architecture question.

I have a class (Controller) and some child classes (ControllerA, ControllerB, ControllerC) that inherit from Controller.

Controller has all of the functionality that allows me to connect to controllers, grab data, grab status updates, etc... The only differences between the child classes are that some of the data they are gathering is different from controller to controller.

Here are a couple of problems I believe I'm facing:

1. Getting similar statuses from the various child controllers (like ConnectionStatus)
2. Binding the controllers in XAML

Here are some examples of each of those concerns:

**1)** Having the child controllers in a list named Controllers of type List[Controller] is convenient for when checking the status of the controllers because I can just loop through the list and easily check the status or data.

For example:

```
foreach (Controller controller in Controllers) {
    Console.WriteLine(controller.ConnectionStatus);
}
```

**2)** But I'm unsure of how to bind to a specific controller's data if they're all in one list.

For example, let's say a ControllerA object is the first object in the Controllers list:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Controllers[0].ControllerAData}" />
```

That doesn't work because ControllerAData doesn't appear in the Controller class.

I could create separate lists for each child controller type (ControllerAs, ControllerBs, ControllerCs), but then it becomes harder to loop through each controller and get their status and data like I've shown in example #1.

What's a good approach to solving these issues?

Thank  you!

Comment: "*That doesn't work because ControllerAData doesn't appear in the Controller class*" is not true. If `Controllers[0]` is a `ControllerA`, the Binding will just work, because it uses reflection to access the actual object type and bind to its `ControllerAData` property.

Comment: @Clemens - I wish that were true but here's what I'm seeing:

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ControllerAData' property not found on 'object' ''Controller'

Comment: `Controllers[0]` is apparently not a `ControllerA` instance, but just a `Controller`

Comment: This is how I'm adding it to the list:

ControllerA controllerA = new ControllerA();
Controllers.Add(controllerA);

It adds just fine, but the binding is saying it can't read the public property.

Comment: Are you sure that `ControllerAData` is a public property of the ControllerA class?

Comment: Yeah, it's public. And all of the classes are public too.

Comment: A public property with a private backing field. Like this:

public class ControllerA : Controller
{

    private string _controllerAData;

    public string ControllerAData
    {
        get { return _controllerAData; }
        set
        {
            _controllerAData = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

}

Comment: Sorry, but your issue is not reproducible. If you add a ControllerA to an empty `List<Controller>`, you can bind to its public ControllerAData property by `{Binding Controllers[0].ControllerAData}`. There must be something you haven't show us.

Comment: I just figured it out. Sorry for my ignorance and you're of great help! So I was pulling in the data from an XML file that wasn't bringing in a type of ControllerA but just plain old Controller. On top of that, I had to include [XmlInclude(typeof(ControllerA))] at the top of my Controller class. Everything works as expected now.

Answer (score -1):

You can keep the controllers in a list but still bind to individual controllers.

```
var controllerA = new ControllerA();
controllerList.Add(controllerA);

windowA.DataContext = controllerA;
```

Within the window you will have binding paths relative to this specific controller. The list remains invisible for the bindings.

Btw.: if you are binding to controllers, shouldn't they be named view models?